# Favourite questions and answers from the 2nd quarter of 2018

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

Another quarter ended.

Following the tradition, we would ask the community again to link your favorite questions and answers created from **1st April 2018 to 30th June 2018**.

You can search all the eligible [questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2018-04..2018-06) and [answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+created%3A2018-04..2018-06) posted the past quarter. Since we got 731 questions and ~1k answers in the past quarter, to make your job easier, here are some data queries.

- [Questions with the most number of votes from the second quarter](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738289/questions-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018/04/01)
- [Questions with the most number of views from the second quarter](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738288/questions-with-most-views-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018/04/01)
- [Answers with most number of votes from the second quarter](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738290/answers-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018/04/01)

The above questions and answers are only for your hint. Feel free to mention any question or answer you enjoyed. Since this is not a competition, there's no need to mention one question or answer per one answer. Also don't hesitate to mention our own questions and answers which you think didn't get the appreciation they deserved.

Answer (score 3):

**Favorite Questions:**

1. [Flying Dutchman](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/63116)'s question [**How does the title 'The Imitation Game' justify the story of the movie?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/87941/27264).
2. [Charles](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/31426)' question [**Was this a movie reference when Tony said “happy trails, kid!” to Spider-Man?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/88845/27264).
3. [Shalini](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/16058)'s question [**Why does Hulk act the way he does in Avengers: Infinity War?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/88486/27264).
4. [Flying Dutchman](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/63116)'s question [**What is the meaning of the lines recited by V prior to saving Evey from fingermen?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/87901/27264).
5. [Steelersquirrel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22792)'s question [**Was Deborah Voorhees cast due to her surname?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/87965/27264).

Answer (score 3):

**Favorite Answers:**

1. **Nikhil Eshwar**'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/87969/27264) to "Was Deborah Voorhees cast due to her surname?".
2. **Rocky**'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/88861/27264) to "Was this a movie reference when Tony said “happy trails, kid!” to Spider-Man?".
3. **Todd Wilcox**'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/89226/27264) to "Why is water so scarce in “The Expanse”?".
4. **Ukemi**'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/88044/27264) to "What kind of grin was Raj hinted to have?".
5. **iandotkelly**'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/89139/27264) to "Does a horror movie have to have supernatural elements?".

Answer (score 3):

**FAVORITE QUESTIONS:**

- **M.A.R.**'s question [What was the window drawing's significance to Hedwig in Split?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88300/what-was-the-window-drawings-significance-to-hedwig-in-split)
- **Charles**'s question [Did Charlie Chaplin fund and produce The Great Dictator alone?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88864/did-charlie-chaplin-fund-and-produce-the-great-dictator-alone)
- **John Joe**'s question [Is there a name for when a creator plays a long-term character in their own motion picture?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88237/is-there-a-name-for-when-a-creator-plays-a-long-term-character-in-their-own-moti)
- **A J**'s question [Why doesn't the regeneration power make the deformed face of Jason like before in Jason X?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88109/why-doesnt-the-regeneration-power-make-the-deformed-face-of-jason-like-before-i)

Answer (score 3):

**FAVORITE ANSWERS:**

- **Nog Shine**'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88182/what-is-daltons-full-name/88183#88183) to "What is Dalton's full name?"
- **Todd Wilcox**'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85790/who-is-the-first-impression-when-robin-williams-is-becoming-mrs-doubfire/89399#89399) to "Who is the first impression when Robin Williams is becoming Mrs. Doubtfire?"
- **Ankit Sharma**'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88109/why-doesnt-the-regeneration-power-make-the-deformed-face-of-jason-like-before-i/88110#88110) to "Why doesn't the regeneration power make the deformed face of Jason like before in Jason X?"
- **Memor-X**'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89167/what-was-meant-by-groot-saying-we-are-groot/89168#89168) to "What was meant by Groot saying 'We are Groot'?"
- **Stephen Francis**'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89934/why-different-footage-was-used-for-garcon-coffee-callback/89945#89945) to "Why different footage was used for "Garcon, coffee" callback?"